# Game optimisation in java concerning ArrayList<Object> elements casting to another variable inside for loop

Tags: java, libgdx

Is this usage of elements of an ArrayList:

```
    for(int i=0; i<array_list.size(); i++){ 
        Object obj = array_list.get(i); 
        //do **lots** of stuff with **obj**
    }
```

faster than this one:

```
    for(int i=0; i<array_list.size(); i++){ 
        //do **lots** of stuff with **array_list.get(i)**; 
    }
```

Comment: Can you please come up with better title?

Comment: What have you measured?

Comment: The JIT might optimize the second version to be equivalent to the first one. Code quality wise the first one is better because you can give your object a descriptive name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how many times `array_list.get(i)` is called in the second code. If it is called only once, there is no difference between both methods.

If it's invoked multiple times, saving the value in a variable may be more efficient (it depends on the compiler and the JIT optimizations).

Sample scenario where the first method may be more efficient, compiled using Oracle JDK's `javac` compiler, assuming the list contains `String` objects:

```
for(int i=0; i<array_list.size(); i++){ 
    String obj = array_list.get(i); 
    System.out.println(obj);

    if(!obj.isEmpty()) {
        String o = obj.substring(1);
        System.out.println(o + obj);
    }
}
```

In this case, `obj` is saved as a local variable and loaded whenever it is used.

```
for(int i=0; i<array_list.size(); i++){ 
    System.out.println(array_list.get(i));

    if(!array_list.get(i).isEmpty()) {
        String o = array_list.get(i).substring(1);
        System.out.println(o + array_list.get(i));
    }
}
```

In this case, multiple invokation for `List.get` are observed in the bytecode.

Comment: even in the latter situation I doubt it will make any difference once the JIT compiles that method...

Comment: @gogonapel I think first approach will be better, as you wont have method calls.

Answer (score 1):

The performance difference between getting once and a local variable is almost always neglible. But... if you insist on doing it the hardcore way, this is the fast way to go:

```
ArrayList<Object> array_list = ...
// cache list.size() in variable!
for (int i=0, e=array_list.size(); i < e; ++i) {
    // get object only once into local variable
    Object object = array_list.get(i);
    // do things with object
}
```

It caches the lists size into a local variable e, to avoid invoking array_list.size() at each loop iteration, as well as each element in the loop to avoid get(index) calls. Be aware that whatever you actually *do* with the objects in the loop will most likely be by orders of magnitude more expensive than the loop itself.

Therefore, prefer code readability and simply use the advanced for loop syntax:

```
ArrayList<Object> array_list = ...
for (Object object : array_list) {
    // do things with object
}
```

No hassles, short and clear. Thats worth far more than a few saved clock cycles in most cases.